# EF code first: inheriting from common base class, WEB api losing base properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to use the following as a base class for all my classes:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public abstract class EsBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public bool SoftDelete { get; set; }
}
```

With example child class:

```
public class Match : EsBase
{                
    [Display(Name = "Start time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that when Match object is sent out through WEB API I do not have access to ID or SoftDelete.

How to pass these as well into output?

Comment: Do you have `[DataMember]` attributes on them?

Comment: As @FrankFajardo said, you have to put [DataMember] on the properties which should be preserved during inter-process communication.
My concern is different - why do you need to make Guid ID DB generated. The big advantage of GUID IDs that they are virtually globally unique, so it can be client side generated, which significantly simplifies design

Comment: Awesome, DataMember is the answer! Thank you both! @FrankFajardo if you add as answer I can mark it.

Comment: @DenisItskovich, I will think about better practices regarding the Guid

Comment: @kravits88, glad to help :)

Comment: show your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to the properties of your DataContract class. This then makes those properties become part of the serialization of your DataContract object.

Comment: this is going to be the shortest accepted answer on SO. I suggest just write `attribute` as `attr`, `your` as `ur` and `properties` as `props`, it will become harder for any other answer to break the record set by this answer. It's also possible to use `+` instead of `add` and even omit the last full stop `.`.

Comment: @Hopeless, I added some info. Does that help you?

Comment: actually I really like the short answer, as I said it would be a record. To understand more I can try reading the link of course.

Comment: is `DataMember` anyway  necessary for `WebApi`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, short answer to your question is no. But as soon as you decorate your class with `DataContract`, you need to decorate your class properties with `DataMemberAttribute` if you want those properties to be serialized/deserialized.